# Reflect on a Point to the North of France

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> The first among physicians,
>   He always flies alone.
>   He's used by some musicians,
>   He speaks in monotone.
>   A dull and shiftless fellow
>   Right in the end we see
>   That bands of black and yellow
>   Reveal who he may be.

The answer is a single English word

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first among physicians,

> Dr One

He always flies alone.

> A drone is a remotely controlled aircraft, an unmanned aerial vehicle.

He's used by some musicians,

> One of the fixed-pitch pipes on a bagpipe.

He speaks in monotone.

> To speak in a dull flat tone.

A dull and shiftless fellow

> A lazy person, an idler who shifts less.

Right in the end we see,

> **r**ight in **done** (the end) we see drone - credit for this is due to *Fillet*.

That bands of black and yellow, Reveal who he may be.

> A drone is a male bee or wasp which does not work but can fertilize the queen.

Title: Reflect on a Point to the North of France

> Nord (North in France) reflected is Dron, and add a point E(ast) for drone.

Comment: Yeah, that fits a lot better than my guess. +1!

Comment: @Glorfindel, +1 yours, it very becoming and believable. Whether it's this or yours - that is the question.

Comment: I think "Right in the end" is another standalone cryptic clue leading to your answer (+1)

Comment: Well done! And what @Fillet said. :-)

Comment: @Fillet, well spotted and solved. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Oh no! The head of the Death Eaters has Harry's best friend!

Answer (score 14):

Is it

> (the letter) B?

Reflect on a Point to the North of France

> North of France lies Belgium, they use the letter B for e.g. the [vehicle registration code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_vehicle_registration_code).

He always flies alone.

> Outside their nest, bees usually fly alone.

He's used by some musicians,

> B is one of the seven [musical notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note).

Right in the end we see

> 'be' is the last word of the riddle

That bands of black and yellow

> A 'bee' has black and yellow stripes

(more to follow, though it's not really a single English word, I guess)